# Parsing response of Axis 2 web Service in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, apache-axis

I am using KSOAP2 to call a Axis 2 webservice from android application,and the response from the web service is in the following format:

```
[Book{id=1; name=C++ for Begginers; Author=Martin;},Book{id=2; name=Java Development; Author=Charles;},Book{id=3; name=Android Guide; Author=Sam};]
```

The code for Axis 2 Web service class is as following:

```
 public class Book_Web_Service {
 private String url;
 private Connection con;
 private Statement stmt;

 public void connectToDB() {
  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book";
  try {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Error - Unable to Connect to the Database" + e);

  }
 }

 public ArrayList<Book> getBooksData() {
     ArrayList<Book> booklist = new ArrayList<Book>();
  connectToDB();

  try {
   stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();

   String query ="SELECT * from book ";
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
   while (rs.next()) {

       Book b = new Book();
      b.setId(rs.getString("id"));
      b.setName(rs.getString("name"));
      b.setAuthor(rs.getString("author"));

       booklist.add(b);
   }
  }

   catch (SQLException e) {
       System.out.println("Error - Unable to get books data ......" + e);
      }
  return booklist;
 }
 }
```

The code for getting response in android is this:

```
ArrayList<Book> booklist = new ArrayList<Book>();


METHOD_NAME = "getBooksData";
try {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    Object result = envelope.getResponse();


    // SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
    String response = result.toString();


    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.booktxt)).setText("Response:"+ response);
} catch (Exception E) {
    E.printStackTrace();
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.booktxt)).setText("ERROR:"
            + E.getClass().getName() + ":" + E.getMessage());
}
```

I want the response again be in arraylist. So that I can show it in list view. But I am not getting it. Is there any android library which can do this or any easy way to do it????